# Avoid nested json fields from deserializing

Tags: apex, json

I have a sample json as follows:

```
{
   "Id": "someid",
   "FirstName": "firstName",
   "nestedField": {
      "LastName": "lastname"
   }
}
```

If I deserialize it like the following, the "Lastname" is being set even though it is in a nested json object. How can I avoid it?

```
String request = '{"Id": "0036D00000H24cKQAR","FirstName": "firstName","nestedField": {"LastName": "lastname"}}';
Contact c = (Contact)JSON.deserialize(request, Contact.class);
System.debug(c);
```

Comment: use JSON.deserializestrict; deserialize ignore extra and consider matching ones

Answer (score -1):

There is no attribute 'nestedField' in the standard contact, hence you can't deserialize it to standard contact record. But you can write a wrapper class such as

```
public class ContactWrapper {

public class NestedField {
    public String LastName;
}
public String Id;
public String FirstName;
public NestedField nestedField; }
```

and then use it as

```
ContactWrapper cw = (ContactWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(request,ContactWrapper);
```

then you can traverse it to the last name such as :-

```
string lname = cw.nestedField.LastName
```

As per your JSON structure , lname will have value = "lastname"

Comment: No. Extraneous fields are allowed in `deserialize`. They are not allowed in `deserializeStrict`, which you are talking about.